# Подмена кода страницы

Tags: javascript, html, css

Любой пользователь может нажать правую кнопку мыши ,посмотреть код и там например подменить текст или графику на сайте. Можно как нибудь остследить что человек занимается этим или нет такой технической возможности?

Comment: Отследить правую кнопку можно, вот только не везде используют правую кнопку. Могут еще нажать F12.

Comment: Всякое можно отследить, но любую "защиту" можно обойти) Если блокировать меню - смогут открыть через CTRL + SHIFT + I. Закрыть и эту комбинацию - могут изначально открыть консоль, потом загрузить вашу страницу. Вычислять размеры окна - откроют в новом окне. В целом, для ответа нужно изначально знать, для какой цели хочется отслеживать это дело: Вдруг уже существует другой, более эффективный подход (уже на стороне сервера).

Comment: извините конечно, вам может показаться резким, но мне правда интересно, зачем, а главное н...я ? Ну а если по существу, то блокировать хоткеи и тд бессмысленно, а отследить думаю практически невозможно, тк изменения происходят в браузере юзера. Разве что теоритически как вариант, js-ом Nное кол-во раз в определённый промежуток времени сверять код на клиенте и на сервере